# Amazon CloudFormation. How to edit existing template

Tags: java, templates, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have existing template (JSON file). I need to generate a new one from it, with different number of stacks (for example 2 instances with Cassandra on board, existing template have only one described and it needs to be copied). How can I achieve that using Java?

Comment: I have found a way to navigate and modify JSON using com.amazonaws.util.json packadge (JSONObject, JSONArray, ....)

Comment: this is a tough question to answer. Do you want to edit raw JSON in java? Do you want to manipulate an already-existing stack? Do you want to parameterize parts of your template?

Comment: I want to parameterize parts of my template (for example add one more stack)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the Cloudformation Stack template to make the necessary changes you need. Based on your question I can not see why you would want to do the actual edits to the template in Java.

Here is the [AWS Guide documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html) on modifying a running Cloudformation Stack. If the number of instances is something that might change I would suggest adding a Parameter to your template so you can easily define the number of instances to create.

You can set up the instances to be members in an Auto-Scaling Group with a Launch Configuration, [here is an AWS snippet example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html). This makes it really simple to easily change the minimum, maximum and desired number of instances you want running.